# Where to put diamond operator type in Java

Tags: java

What is the difference between these two lines of code? I've always been using the first one but I never knew why. I don't know which one is right since netbeans isn't giving me an error (I haven't compiled yet).

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList test2 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: The best option would be coding to the interface (`List`) as opposed to implementation (`ArrayList`) and declaring the variable as `List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second is **bad** because you're dropping the generic.

The first is just shorthand for:

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Which makes a bigger difference if you have a Map of List:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>(); // much nicer
```

Comment: I know how generics are used as in your last two lines. Could you please elaborate on how I am dropping the generic. Don't I use it on the right hand side? Or do I have to declare generics on both sides as you did in your last line?

Comment: @Aeleon In the second line `test2` has type `ArrayList` (no generics) for the same reason that in `double d = 4;` `d` has type `double` (even though there's an `int` on the right hand side)

Comment: Generics is a compile-time gimmick. Your `test2` variable is a *raw* `ArrayList`, like from before generics were added, which means it's just a list of objects, no type safety, not restricted to Strings.